# Appropriate Phrasing: The ensuing topics are

Tags: semantics, phrasing, appropriate

I'm co-writing the editorial for an upcoming magazine and I am unsure about the phrasing of a particular sentence. Is the usage of the word "ensuing" appropriate in the following sentence?:

> The ensuing topics are of scientific, philosophical, investigative and
>   literary nature.

The sentence is supposed to serve as an introduction to the magazine's main focus and is preceded and followed by two other introductory sentences:

> The basic idea of the following publication is the multi-perspective
>   contemplation of a thing, fundamental to humans: the misrepresentation
>   of reality. The ensuing topics are of scientific, philosophical,
>   investigative and literary nature. The goal is an attempt at compiling insights into the multitude of ways and reasons how and why people perceive, believe and deceive.

What would be an appropriate alternative? I welcome all advice on how to improve the phrasing.

Comment: We need more context to determine if 'ensue' is the right verb or not.  Can you provide more details?

Comment: @JohnFeltz Thank you for responding. The sentence is serving as an introduction to the magazine's main focus. I'm adding the preceding sentence in order to clarify the context.

Comment: Proofreading, writing advice and criticism questions are off topic because they do not help anyone but the asker, unless there is a clearly identified source of concern which would be interesting to many future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can talk about the ensuing articles, but the "ensuing topics" wouldn't be so good.  The "ensuing articles" means the articles that will follow this introduction.

Comment: what would be a suitable synonym for 'ensuing'?

Comment: @JohnGalt - Is the intro in the Question an intro to the magazine as a whole?

Comment: It is.

Would 'emerging' be an appropriate synonym to use here?

Comment: @JohnGalt - The basic idea of this publication is the multi-perspective contemplation of something that is fundamental to humans: the misrepresentation of reality. The topics contemplate are of scientific, philosophical, investigative or literary nature. The goal is to compile insights into the multitude of ways and reasons how and why people perceive, believe and deceive. Just a suggestion.  Feel free to rework any of what I just wrote.

Answer (score -1):

I think "ensuing" is perfectly appropriate, since the word ensuing implies being derived from ( the study of the misrepresentation of reality), not just following.